# How to print match pattern using sed/awk?(I was able to do this with grep)

Tags: linux

I need to print only the 11 tag using awk or sed only with WHILE loop.

```
Order:479959,60=20130624-09:45:02.046|35=D|11=884|38=723|21=1|1=30532|10=085|59=0|114=Y|56=MBT|40=1|43=Y|100=MBTX|55=/GCQ3|49=11342|54=1|8=FIX.4.4|34=388|553=2453|9=205|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|
Order:24780,100=MBTX|43=Y|40=1|34=388|553=2453|52=2013062409:45:02.046|9=205|49=11342|54=1|8=FIX.4.4|55=/GCQ3|11=405|35=D|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|56=MBT|59=0|114=Y|10=085|21=1|38=470|1=30532|
Order:799794,55=/GCQ3|49=11342|54=1|8=FIX.4.4|34=388|553=2453|9=205|52=2013062409:45:02.046|40=1|43=Y|100=MBTX|38=350|21=1|1=30532|10=085|59=0|114=Y|56=MBT|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|35=D|11=216|
Order:72896,11=735|35=D|60=2013062409:45:02.046|56=MBT|59=0|114=Y|10=085|1=30532|38=17|21=1|100=MBTX|43=Y|40=1|553=2453|9=205|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|34=388|8=FIX.4.4|54=1|49=11342|55=/GCQ3|
```

The output should be like this:-

```
Orderid-479959 38= 723 Clientid=884
Orderid-24780 38= 470 Clientid=405
Orderid-799794 38= 350 Clientid=216
```

Comment: How did you do that with `grep`?

Comment: grep -oE '11=[^|]+' report.txt

Comment: Ah, but that is nothing like your desired output.

Comment: @SonalAsija That `grep` pattern would also match `111=`. Better use `[|,]11=[^|]+` if you're doing it that way.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://askubuntu.com/q/867664/158442

Comment: Your requirement, "_print only the 11 tag_" doesn't match the desired output. Please [edit] your question to make sure you clearly state what is actually required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A "clean" awk solution**

Some `awk` one-shot command with formatted output version if you're interested (although this looks like a job well suited for `sed`):

```
awk -F'\\||,' '{
                   for (i=1;i<NF+1;i++) {
                     if ($i ~ /11=.*/) {
                       split($i, a, "=")                           
                     }
                     if ($i ~ /Order:.*/) {
                       split($i, b, ":")
                     }
                     if ($i ~ /38=.*/) {
                       split($i, c, "=")
                     }
                   }
                   printf "Orderid-%-10s 38= %-8s Clientid=%s\n", b[2], c[2], a[2]
                 }' < infile.txt
```

If you're so keen on not using `awk`, `sed` or `tr`, and absolutely want a shell while loop, please be advised as already said in comments that this is a very bad practice to have. There is extensive explanation of *why* it is so bad [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

---

**The "don't do it" solution**

Now that we have made this little disclaimer, here is a way to achieve your output using only bash string manipulation within a while loop (script form, and of course it **only works in bash**):

```
while read line; 
do
  x=${line#*11=}
  x=${x%%|*}
  y=${line#*:}
  y=${y%%,*}
  z=${line#*38=}
  z=${z%%|*}
  echo "Orderid-$y 38= $z Clientid=$x"
done < infile.txt
```

In your particular example it works, but *please* don't do this in a "real life" situation. The basic idea in any shell is: "the least calls to external tools, the better". So ideally if you can do the job in one call like in my awk example, do it. Awk will be loaded *once* and then the whole job is done in C, which is lightning fast compared to shell.

---

**How string manipulation in bash works in my answer**

- `${string#pattern}`: start from the left-hand side of the string, and deletes the *shortest* match for patern. So if you put a pattern like `*a` for example, everything up to the *first* "a" character (included) will be removed from your string. If you use the same syntax but with 2 "#", the match for `pattern` will become as greedy as possible, and remove everything up to the last "a" character in your string. Example:

  ```
  $ test="alakazam"; echo ${test#*a}; echo ${test##*a};
  lakazam
  m
  ```
- `${string%pattern}`: works the same, but from the right-hand side. To illustrate with previous example:

  ```
  $ test="alakazam"; echo ${test%a*}; echo ${test%%a*};
  alakaz
               #no output here: the whole string is matched by pattern
  ```

Comment: Thanks... could you plz explain me x=${line##*11=} x=${x%%|*} how its working?

Comment: I'll edit the post with some level of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop:

```
$ sed 's/^.*[,|]11=\([^|]*\).*$/client id = \1/' data.in
client id = 884
client id = 405
client id = 216
client id = 735
```

The editing script will look for the `11` tag (`11=` preceded by either `|` or `,`), and replace the whole line with the text `client id =` followed by the number after the `11=` (actually *anything* following the `11=` up to a `|` or end of line).

UPDATE (after new problem spec.):

This is `uglyscript.sh` (requires GNU `sed` and GNU `awk`):

```
#!/bin/sh
tr ',|' '\n' |
awk -vRS="\n\n" '{ print | "sort -r"; close("sort -r") }' |
tr '\n' '|' |
sed 's/|Order/\nOrder/g' |
sed 's/^Order:\([^|]*\).*|\(38=[^|]*\).*|11=\([^|]*\).*$/Orderid-\1 \2 Clientid=\3/'
echo
```

1. The first `tr` turns all rows in the input data into one column.  The original lines are separated by a blank line (two newlines) in its output.
2. The `awk` sorts each set of lines separately in reverse lexicographical order (so that "Order" comes first).
3. The second `tr`, together with the following `sed` puts the lines back together again, but now the columns are in a sorted order. The `tr` just replaces all newlines with a `|` character, while the `sed` breaks the lines wherever the string `|Order` is found.
4. The last `sed` is similar to my original solution, but just captures a few more things from the lines.
5. The `echo` at the end just ensures that there is a newline at the end of the output.

Steps 1 to 3 above are necessary since the columns are not sorted. The column containing `11=` can come anywhere on the line, for example, which makes just running it through a single `sed` script very difficult.

The data, after step 3, looks like this:

```
Order:479959|9=205|8=FIX.4.4|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|553=2453|54=1|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|49=11342|43=Y|40=1|38=723|35=D|34=388|21=1|1=30532|11=884|114=Y|10=085|100=MBTX
Order:24780|9=205|8=FIX.4.4|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|553=2453|54=1|52=2013062409:45:02.046|49=11342|43=Y|40=1|38=470|35=D|34=388|21=1|1=30532|11=405|114=Y|10=085|100=MBTX
Order:799794|9=205|8=FIX.4.4|60=20130624-09:45:02.046|59=0|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|553=2453|54=1|52=2013062409:45:02.046|49=11342|43=Y|40=1|38=350|35=D|34=388|21=1|1=30532|11=216|114=Y|10=085|100=MBTX
Order:72896|9=205|8=FIX.4.4|60=2013062409:45:02.046|59=0|56=MBT|55=/GCQ3|553=2453|54=1|52=20130624-09:45:02.046|49=11342|43=Y|40=1|38=17|35=D|34=388|21=1|1=30532|11=735|114=Y|10=085|100=MBTX|
```

Running it:

```
$ ./uglyscript.sh <data.in
Orderid-479959 38=723 Clientid=884
Orderid-24780 38=470 Clientid=405
Orderid-799794 38=350 Clientid=216
Orderid-72896 38=17 Clientid=735
```

Comment: @SonalAsija Not really: `somecommand | sed '(the sed script)' >outputfile`

Comment: could you plz explain me :- $/client id = \1/ ? thanks

Comment: @SonalAsija `/client id = \1/` is the replacement in `s/pattern/replacement/`. It means that the pattern should be replaced by the text `client id =` followed by whatever is captured by the first _group_. The first (and only) group is the `\( ... \)` in the pattern. It captures the actual client ID, i.e. everything after `11=` up to the following `|` or newline.

Comment: my professor told me to use only While loop and the output should be:-                   Orderid-479959 38= 723 Clientid=884,  Orderid-24780 38= 470 Clientid=405,Orderid-799794 38= 350 Clientid=216 ... any help will be appreciated

Comment: @SonalAsija Imposing a ridiculous restriction like that only makes the problem more difficult. The while loop is implicit in the `sed` command (it is looping over the lines). I will modify my answer, but I will not add a while loop when none is needed.

Comment: is it possible to get output without using tr and awk?

Comment: Why? Awk was part of the original problem specification. Why do you want to make it more complicated? If your professor is giving you an assignment, with restrictions like that, then I would ask him if he's ever seen a Unix systems with only `sed` installed on it.

Comment: @SonalAsija I'll add that the _reason_ I'm refusing to use a while loop is that when you start getting gigabyte datasets, looping over the rows with a shell while loop is going to be rather slow, to say the least. It's bad enough to start a `sort` process for each line. Just add a few thousand lines of data and you'll see the script grind slowly through it. If this was a professional problem, I'd get you to submit a bug report to the person who wrote the code that created the data. That code is broken.